# how to fix chessboardjs theme not working

Tags: javascript, chessboard.js

I know this is so simple but my boardTheme doesn't work?

```
const startPos = 'start';
const config = {
    draggable: true,
    position: startPos,
    boardTheme: ['#ffffff', '#000000'], // white and black
    onDragStart: onDragStart,
    onDrop: onDrop,
    onSnapEnd: onSnapEnd
}
```

when I open the website it's still the default theme.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your style file:

```
.white-1e1d7 {
  background-color: #ffffff; /* Background of the white side tiles */
  color: #000000; /* color of the letter identifing the files (columns) */
}

.black-3c85d {
  background-color: #000000; /* Background of the black side tiles */
  color: #ffffff; /* color of the letter identifing the ranks (rows) */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

bro this problem is because as you wrote the code:-

```
boardTheme: ['#ffffff', '#000000']
```

Do you know
#ffffff is white color and #000000 means black color.

Comment: so what;s the problem?